# Need help to optimize the Excel VBA code that aggregates duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my source table

```
    Name              Sales
---------------------------------
    Thomas             100
    Jay                200
    Thomas             100
    Mathew              50
```

Output I need is as below

```
    Name              Sales
---------------------------------
    Thomas             200
    Jay                200
    Mathew              50
```

Basically, I have 2 columns that can have duplicates and I need to aggregate the second column based on first column.

Current code I have is as below. Its working perfectly fine. It takes around 45 seconds to run for 4500 records. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this... as it seems to be a trivial requirement.

```
'Combine duplicate rows and sum values

Dim Rng As Range
Dim LngRow As Long, i As Long

LngLastRow = lRow 'The last row is calculated somewhere above...

'Initializing the first row
i = 1

'Looping until blank cell is encountered in first column
While Not Cells(i, 1).Value = ""

    'Initializing range object
    Set Rng = Cells(i, 1)

    'Looping from last row to specified first row
    For LngRow = LngLastRow To (i + 1) Step -1

        'Checking whether value in the cell is equal to specified cell
        If Cells(LngRow, 1).Value = Rng.Value Then
            Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value + Cells(LngRow, 2).Value
            Rows(LngRow).Delete
        End If

    Next LngRow

    i = i + 1

Wend
```

Note that this is part of a larger excel app and hence I definitely need the solution to be in Excel VBA.

Comment: To be honest, you're probably better off asking optimization questions on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), if the code already works.

Comment: Loop through all the cells with a dictionary, if the item exists, add the values, if it doesn't add the item and it's value. When it's done just paste the keys and items from the dictionary. That should take barely 5 seconds

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the tip, I was unaware of the same. Will a moderator move it or do I need to create a duplicate question there?

Comment: Thanks @Damian. Let me do some research on Dictionary... Never used it. Appreciate if someone can help with the implementation.

Comment: Also turn screenupdating off

Comment: @supajason Yes, missed to mention... its already off. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Unless it's required to be coded, I'd like to mention that "Aggregate one column based on another" is exactly what the built in PivotTables are there for.

Comment: @LWChris Totally Agree. However, as I mentioned, this is just a small part of an "automation app" in Excel. So it needs to be in the code.

Comment: @ThomasKoipuram Yes. Maybe other users who are stopping by while trying to reinvent the wheel just to see aggregated data will find this useful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Consolidate()

    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Sales As New Scripting.Dictionary 'You will need the library Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'speed up the code since excel won't show you what is happening

    'First of all, working on arrays always speeds up a lot the code because you are working on memory
    'instead of working with the sheets
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet") 'change this
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column A
        arrData = .Range("A2", .Cells(i, 2)).Value 'here im assuming your row 1 has headers and we are storing the data into an array
    End With

    'Then we create a dictionary with the data
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrData) 'from row 2 to the last on Q1 (the highest)
        If Not Sales.Exists(arrData(i, 1)) Then
            Sales.Add arrData(i, 1), arrData(i, 2) 'We add the worker(Key) with his sales(Item)
        Else
            Sales(arrData(i, 1)) = Sales(arrData(i, 1)) + arrData(i, 2) 'if the worker already exists, sum his sales
        End If
    Next i

    'Now you have all the workers just once
    'If you want to delete column A and B and just leave the consolidate data:
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet") 'change this
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column A
        .Range("A2:B" & i).ClearContents
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(Sales.Count) = Application.Transpose(Sales.Keys) 'workers
        .Cells(2, 2).Resize(Sales.Count) = Application.Transpose(Sales.Items) 'Their sales
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'return excel to normal

End Sub
```

To learn everything about dictionaries (and more) check [this](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for the code and explanation. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With data in cols **A** and **B** like:

[image]

Running this short macro:

```
Sub KopyII()
    Dim cell As Range, N As Long

    Columns("A:A").Copy Range("C1")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B1").Copy Range("D1")

    Range("D2:D" & N).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A= C2),(B:B))"
End Sub
```

will produce this in cols **C** and **D**:

[image]

**NOTE:**

This relies on Excel's builtin RemoveDuplicates feature.

**EDIT#1:**

As chris neilsen points out, this function should be a bit quicker to evaluate:

```
Sub KopyIII()
    Dim cell As Range, N As Long, A As Range, C As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set C = Range("C:C")

    A.Copy C
    C.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B1").Copy Range("D1")  ' the header

    Range("D2:D" & N).Formula = "=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,C2)"
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good (and compact)! I already implemented Damian's solution and it brought down my running time from 45 sec to 4 seconds. So, I am currently sticking with that. But this is a good learning. Thanks!

Comment: Using `SumProduct` on whole columns is a bad idea. [See Here](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2015/12/12/excel-full-column-references-and-used-range-good-idea-or-bad-idea/) (from the conclusion: _Formulas other than array formulas and SUMPRODUCT handle whole column references efficiently._ ) Use the much simpler `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,C2)` instead

Comment: @chrisneilsen  I agree and I updated the Answer.........................Thank you!